Not able to read the updated value in a Solana Data Account
I have a simple solana greeting-counter program, I have it deployed locally. When I am calling from my typescript code I am able to do pretty much all the transactions and verify them. Except the last one, where I am seeing the block explorer is showing the transaction went through it's a success, however when I try to read the data I am seeing the state has not been updated.
Here is the Solana App Code:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("8VEC1cycS5ry9aM5CBRWtxfVQBfNtWANTXXrXXmk2TXw");


#[program]
pub mod hello_please {
    use super::*;
    pub fn create_greeting(ctx: Context<CreateGreeting>) -> Result<()> {
        let greeting_account = &mut ctx.accounts.greeting_account;
        greeting_account.counter = 0;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn increment_greeting(ctx: Context<IncrementGreeting>) -> Result<()> {
        let greeting_account = &mut ctx.accounts.greeting_account;
        greeting_account.counter += 1;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateGreeting<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 8 + 8)]
    pub greeting_account: Account<'info, GreetingAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct IncrementGreeting<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub greeting_account: Account<'info, GreetingAccount>,
}

#[account]
pub struct GreetingAccount {
    pub counter: u64,
}


Here is the IDL in JSON:
{
  "address": "8VEC1cycS5ry9aM5CBRWtxfVQBfNtWANTXXrXXmk2TXw",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "hello_please",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "spec": "0.1.0",
    "description": "Created with Anchor"
  },
  "instructions": [
    {
      "name": "create_greeting",
      "discriminator": [
        230,
        141,
        114,
        135,
        35,
        122,
        88,
        117
      ],
      "accounts": [
        {
          "name": "greeting_account",
          "writable": true,
          "signer": true
        },
        {
          "name": "user",
          "writable": true,
          "signer": true
        },
        {
          "name": "system_program",
          "address": "11111111111111111111111111111111"
        }
      ],
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "name": "increment_greeting",
      "discriminator": [
        58,
        180,
        32,
        32,
        96,
        80,
        100,
        213
      ],
      "accounts": [
        {
          "name": "greeting_account",
          "writable": true
        }
      ],
      "args": []
    }
  ],
  "accounts": [
    {
      "name": "GreetingAccount",
      "discriminator": [
        190,
        16,
        56,
        57,
        246,
        26,
        112,
        24
      ]
    }
  ],
  "types": [
    {
      "name": "GreetingAccount",
      "type": {
        "kind": "struct",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "counter",
            "type": "u64"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

Here is the typescript code:
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import * as borsh from "@coral-xyz/borsh";
import { AnchorProvider, Program, Wallet, Idl, web3} from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import idl from "./idl/hello_please.json";

async function main() {

    const connection =  new web3.Connection("http://127.0.0.1:8899");
    
    const providerAccount = web3.Keypair.generate();

    console.log(`providerAccount.publicKey: ${providerAccount.publicKey}`);

    console.log(`providerAccount.secretKey: ${providerAccount.secretKey}`);

    const airdrop_txn = await connection.requestAirdrop(providerAccount.publicKey, 10e9);
    const latestBlockHash_1 = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
    await connection.confirmTransaction({
        blockhash: latestBlockHash_1.blockhash,
        lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash_1.lastValidBlockHeight,
        signature: airdrop_txn,
    });
    console.log("Got Latest BlockHash");
    const provider_balance = await connection.getBalance(providerAccount.publicKey);
    console.log(`provider_account_balance: ${provider_balance}`);

    const wallet = new Wallet(providerAccount);
    
    const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, {
    });
    anchor.setProvider(provider);
    console.log("provider set");

    const program = new Program(idl as Idl, provider);
    console.log("program created");

    const greetingAccount = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

    console.log(greetingAccount.publicKey);

    console.log(`greetingAccount created. \r greetingAccount.publicKey: ${greetingAccount.publicKey}`);

    console.log(`Sending Funds to greetingAccount`);
    const send_funds_transaction = new web3.Transaction().add(
        web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
          fromPubkey: providerAccount.publicKey,
          toPubkey: greetingAccount.publicKey,
          lamports: 2e9,
        }),
    );

    const send_funds_signature = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
        connection,
        send_funds_transaction,
        [providerAccount],
    );
    console.log('send_funds_signature', send_funds_signature);

    const greeting_balanace = await connection.getBalance(greetingAccount.publicKey);
    console.log(`Balance of Greeting Account: ${greeting_balanace}`);

    console.log("Before Sending Transaction: CreateGreeting");
    const createGreeting_tx = await program.methods
        .createGreeting()
        .accounts({
            greetingAccount: greetingAccount.publicKey,
        })
        .signers([greetingAccount])
        .rpc();

    console.log("Create Greeting Transaction signature:", createGreeting_tx+"\n");

    await printCounterValue(connection, greetingAccount, createGreeting_tx);

    console.log("Before Sending Transaction: IncrementGreeting");
    const incrementGreeting_tx = await program.methods
        .incrementGreeting()
        .accounts({
            greetingAccount: greetingAccount.publicKey,
        })
        .signers([providerAccount])
        .rpc();

    console.log("Increment Greeting Transaction signature:", incrementGreeting_tx+"\n");

    const isValid = await isValidSignature(connection, incrementGreeting_tx);

    console.log("Transaction Finalized: "+isValid);

    await printLatestBlockhash(connection, incrementGreeting_tx);

    console.log("Transaction Finalized: "+isValid);

    await printCounterValue(connection, greetingAccount, incrementGreeting_tx);

    console.log("Transaction Finalized: "+isValid);

}
main();

interface GreetingAccount {
    counter: anchor.BN
}

const isValidSignature = async (connection: anchor.web3.Connection, sig: string) => {
    const status = await connection.getSignatureStatus(sig, {
      searchTransactionHistory: true,
    });
    return (
      status.value?.err === null &&
      status.value?.confirmationStatus === "finalized"
    );
};

async function printCounterValue(connection: anchor.web3.Connection, greetingAccount: anchor.web3.Keypair, txSignature: string){

    const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

    await connection.confirmTransaction({
        blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
        lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
        signature: txSignature,
      }, 'finalized');
    console.log("Got Latest BlockHash");
    console.log("Transaction finalized. Retrieving updated account state...");

    const accountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(greetingAccount.publicKey);
    if (accountInfo === null) {
        throw new Error("Error: Account not found");
    }
    console.log("account info retrieved");

    const GreetingAccountSchema = borsh.struct<GreetingAccount>([borsh.u64("counter"),]);
    console.log("GreetingAccount Schema constructed");

    const {counter} = GreetingAccountSchema.decode(accountInfo?.data, "processed");
    console.log("GreetingAccount Struct/Type constructed");

    console.log("decoded counter: "+counter.toNumber()+"\n");
}

async function printLatestBlockhash(connection: anchor.web3.Connection, txSignature: string){
    const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

    await connection.confirmTransaction({
        blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
        lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
        signature: txSignature,
      }, 'finalized');
    console.log("Got Latest BlockHash");
}


Just for clarifying,the rust code is being built and deployed locally inside wsl. The typescript code is being called externally in Windows using Gitbash. As you will see below there is no issue so far when I am doing balance transfers and creating the data account, however I am having trouble reading the updated state of the data account(the explorer also confirms the transaction for increment Greeting is success). This is the result when I execute npx tsc && node ./build/index:
providerAccount.publicKey: 3bq44nBYNvJhcwU7XED6hwUFWGWdis3j2boXgtgmNMMc
providerAccount.secretKey: 117,199,146,222,123,138,144,19,26,63,129,43,202,20,26,58,240,92,210,168,65,43,214,187,6,193,156,166,24,57,33,68,38,163,116,115,157,110,105,109,102,165,156,10,252,121,205,229,42,62,247,58,83,157,174,42,88,218,94,30,51,226,173,35
Got Latest BlockHash
provider_account_balance: 10000000000
provider set
program created
PublicKey [PublicKey(8fTkRGZMxXeccGZpX4a9JgUqPWzU1Q6FRr69JCtLVTEF)] {
  _bn: <BN: 71dc1fbbdced2bd2ef5bbe8a86de890fc9c6e17ec9e9a5ea1ff7693df3fd8158>
}
 greetingAccount.publicKey: 8fTkRGZMxXeccGZpX4a9JgUqPWzU1Q6FRr69JCtLVTEF
Sending Funds to greetingAccount
send_funds_signature BeQFTFsf19QNUQjhDUhcnSqpkB9okuz6xFs3HpeUXGvwZ7MsvHRFEri61K4vK4ZE15RH16bGSuQXqLpCM6q97Fc
Balance of Greeting Account: 2000000000
Before Sending Transaction: CreateGreeting
Create Greeting Transaction signature: 3Cku7jdoZVLaWrmy6URz7GgepVvtAwq6HA5W4M9HDbUqfJcPhwsjS5uUVRhB7Z84b3iqnj6Jr1mdCqR52wrTZHxD

Got Latest BlockHash
Transaction finalized. Retrieving updated account state...
account info retrieved
GreetingAccount Schema constructed
GreetingAccount Struct/Type constructed
decoded counter: 0

Before Sending Transaction: IncrementGreeting
Increment Greeting Transaction signature: 4yUhDhcmKCQxCgrkE6CAc9T8vStG6iENUiv1ivAPTGcmoXFcPgsnzoZe2zoRAWeABkay7cTVwgww9DknXeMALKUV

Transaction Finalized: true
Got Latest BlockHash
Transaction Finalized: true
Got Latest BlockHash
Transaction finalized. Retrieving updated account state...
account info retrieved
GreetingAccount Schema constructed
GreetingAccount Struct/Type constructed
decoded counter: 0

Transaction Finalized: true


Tbh should work. Would add a msg!() inside of the increment instruction to see if it actually increase the value.
